# ThinkingSphinx to match exact phrase

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx and ThinkingSphinx gem with Rails 3 for searching.  I want to search for exact match of a certain string for an sphinx-indexed column but there seems to be no good way to do so.  According to ThinkingSphinx documentation, the matching modes are :any, :phrase, :all, but they all seem to search on substring.  For example, searching for "1997" will also match with "1997 Honda", or "1997 Ford".  In my situation, I want to search for the exact match of "1997", thus "1997 Honda" and "1997 Ford" should not match.  This is straightforward with MySQL, but I have not found a way to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx introduced the field-start and field-end operators in version 0.9.9-rc2.

To use your example, you would search for '^1997$'